# Quaternion barycentric interpolation

Tags: geometry, rotations, interpolation, quaternions

Let's say that i have a set of quaternions, each representing a 3-angle orientation. And with each quaternion is associated a real value (let's say a speed value for explanation's sake).

Now with an arbitrary input quaternion, i would like to 1) find the "nearest" quaternions in the set, compute the barycentric coordinates of the input quaternion relative to these neighbours, and 2) use these coordinates to compute a corresponding interpolated speed.

My first thought for this problem was to compute the angle between the input quaternion and each quaternions in the set, and then, select the quaternions with the smallest delta angle. Then each delta angle would give me a relative weight for blending speed values.

Do you think that this approach is correct or do you have better ideas on the way to do this ?

Any help or suggestions would be gladly appreciated.
Thanks !